# Exported TIFF files inconsistent color from CorelDRAW versions

Tags: color, export, corel-draw, tiff

When I export a TIFF file from CorelDRAW X7 the result in CorelDRAW is different when I export from CorelDRAW X4. Why does this happen? What can I do about it?

Comment: I don't think you have given enough information to give you a proper answer. When you set up the document, are you using RGB or CMYK colours. On exporting, is the TIFF CMYK or RGB? Also what colour profiles are you using to export the images?

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust your color profiles

Tools > Color administration > Predefined Settings

There you choose what settings you need.

Also, you need to define if you have a CMYK file or an RGB one.

Answer (score 0):

CorelDraw changed color style after X5 version. It's a big problem and all about with Corel. The quick solution is to use only just one version of Corel. If you have two different files as X4 and X7 you must save on of them for other version.

For example:

1. Open the X7 version of corel.
2. Save it as X4 version
3. Open it in X4 program
4. Export as tiff from X4

Ofcourse you can think the opposite of this too.

You can find a few explanations about this issue:

- http://corelturk.blogspot.com.tr/2008/03/coreldraw-renk-sorunu-ve-renk-ynetimi.html
- http://corelturk.blogspot.com.tr/2013/03/coreldraw-renk-kalibrasyonu-1.html